# Symfony2 Form Validation: strange issue with DateTime

Tags: symfony

I have a team entity with a property like this

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="founded", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $founded;
```

i deliver to the controller method something like this via post:

```
form_team[basicdata][founded]:30.12.1901
```

with this date and beyond the validation passes. when i put in `12.12.1901` and below it fails with the message `This value is not valid.`.

What the hell is happening here?!?!

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTimeValidator` shows the following regexp to validate a user input date:

```
/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/
```

Which does not match your input. You will need to create a custm validator constraint for your specific input. You can find more info in how to do this in the official documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: Even when i delete the DateTime() Constraint it shows me that error: This value is not valid.
And i dont know where this error is produced